# VBA How to programaticly select an item in a listbox without triggering the on click event

Tags: vba, excel-2010, activex

I am using Excel 2010, Windows 10, with VBA. I have a function which runs upon clicking an item in an ActiveX `ListBox` control. The issue is that if you click the list box I ask if they are sure if they want to change the selection. If you click "yes" I continue, but if you say "no" I set the selection back to what it previously was.

So the issue is that when I programmatically set the list box selection back to the previous selection my function will re-run the code that runs if a user clicks an item in the list box ...which is what I don't want.

Does anyone have a better way to stop a list box selection and change it back to the old one without causing the on list box selection event to trigger?

Function prototype for on click of the list box

```
lsQuestions_Click()
```

Code for setting the list box selection

```
'Prototype: setListBoxSelection(query As String, listBoxName As String) As Boolean
'  Purpose: Set listbox selection based on text
Public Function setListBoxSelection(query As String, listBoxName As String) As Boolean
  Dim lsBox As MSForms.listBox
  Set lsBox = Workbooks(mainFile).Worksheets(entrySheet).OLEObjects(listBoxName).Object

  Dim I As Integer

  For I = 0 To lsBox.ListCount - 1
      If lsBox.List(I) = query Then
          lsBox.Selected(I) = True
          setListBoxSelection = True
          Exit Function
      End If
  Next I

  setListBoxSelection = False
End Function
```

Please note that I think the line of code below is what is triggering my click event which is what I don't want.

```
lsBox.Selected(I) = True
```

Comment: Try adding Application.EnableEvents = False at the start of the function and then setting it back to true at the end.  Setting it back to true is *very* important!

Comment: @sous2817 `Application.EnableEvents` controls Excel `Worksheet` and `Workbook` events, it has no bearing on ActiveX handlers for a listbox.

Comment: Where's the `MsgBox` prompt?

Comment: I have a function called checkChangeQuestion inside of question_click. checkChangeQuestion will prompt the user check if I should be giving the user the warning or not then handling yes or no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do this with my VB6 projects is to define a module-scope variable

```
Private blnChangingInCode As Boolean
```

Then, when I need to utilize it, I set it to true, call the even/sub, set it back to false.

```
blnChangingInCode = True
btnLogin_Click()
blnChangingInCode = False
```

Inside the affected subs/events I start with

```
If blnChangingInCode Then
    Exit Sub ' or Exit Function
End if
```

This might not be elegant, but it works, and I don't need to do it very often.

Comment: I would strongly advise against invoking event handlers like this. Event handlers are invoked by an event source, period. Extract a method out of it, make the handler invoke that method, and then call *that extracted method* instead. Don't invoke event handlers. Event handlers handle events, they're implementation details, not public interface. Also the parentheses are superfluous, and actually harmful if there are arguments to pass.

Comment: The issue though is I am not calling the click event. It seems to be getting called when I set the selection on the listbox

Comment: "lsBox.Selected(I) = True" This is what seems to be triggering my click event